# Displaying similar nodes

Tags: drupal, view, panels

I've somewhat ran in to a problem with Drupal today.

I would like to display a node (Product) on a page, and below that node, I'd like to display 3 similar nodes (Products). Similar being: having the same taxonomy id or having a "promoted" tag attached to it.

I've tried crafting the related nodes into a view which is being displayed as a block, only when we're on a product's page. I didn't get far with this.

My second thought was making a panel page with 2 views on it, one for the product, and one for the related products. I also didn't get far with this.

Does anybody know the easiest way to accomplish this?

**Update:**

I have tried both answers, I am not receiving any related products though. The SQL query that's executed (term id = 1) is:

```
SELECT node.type AS node_type, node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created FROM  {node} node INNER JOIN {taxonomy_index} taxonomy_index_value_0 ON node.nid = taxonomy_index_value_0.nid AND taxonomy_index_value_0.tid = :views_join_condition_0 WHERE (( (node.type IN ('product')) AND (taxonomy_index_value_0.tid AND '') AND( (taxonomy_index_value_0.tid IN ('1')) ))) ORDER BY node_created DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

When I manually execute the query and remove `AND (taxonomy_index_value_0.tid AND '')` from the query I do receive the related products.

Does anybody know what causes the code to be added to the query and how to fix it?

**Update 2:**
I've removed the "Allow Multiple Terms per Argument" and am now getting the related products. I don't know what this means for my site though.

**Update 3:**
I am using Drupal 7 by the way.

Comment: It sounds like you are on the right track, what specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: I'm having trouble displaying the similar products. I don't know the best way to handle this problem. I don't know how to handle the parameters, if I have to handle them at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override your node view with panels. And create a view block with 'taxonomy id argument', you need to choose default argument options as PHP Code and place this code.

```
$node = node_load(arg(1));
if($node) {
    foreach($node->taxonomy as $term) {
        $term = $term->tid;
        return $term;
    }   
}
```

I just launched a site using panels + views magic.  http://sgigulf.org/culture/synopsis-of-performers-showcased-by-sgi-gulf

Comment: Could you elaborate somewhat more please? I'm new to drupal.

Comment: With Panels you can override default node display. Go to admin/build/pages, enable 'node view', click edit and and add a variant. click 'selection rules' and choose the node type you would like to override. If you have done properly, you should get blank page for your node. Now add your node content on one side and place your views with default argument with PHP code mentioned above. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the RelatedContent module. Links to the module and a couple of tutorials below:

- http://drupal.org/project/relatedcontent
- http://drupaleasy.com/blogs/ryanprice/2008/06/using-views-2-drupal-6-create-a-related-pages-block
- http://www.hankpalan.com/blog/drupal/related-content-views-2-drupal

You say you're having trouble with the display. In that casea, make the view from the above instructions a block, and have it display in a region that's below the node content, though that assumes there's a region in your theme directly below your content.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple terms when you change to

```
$node = node_load(arg(1));
if ($node) {
    $ret = array();
    foreach ($node->taxonomy as $term) {
        $ret[] =  $term->tid;
    }   
    return implode('+', $ret);
}
return '';
```

The '+' in implode is OR. If you want AND, than use ',' instead